# Insert dynamically-added row values into database

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, jsp-tags

I want to insert dynamic values into my database but I'm unable to insert.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#customFieldValue").val(); i++) {}
    
    $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th>  <td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');

  });
  
  /*
  for (var i = 0; i < $("#customFieldValue").val(); i++) {
  }
  */
  
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
  <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
      <label for="customFieldName">Custom Field
      </label>
    </th>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
      <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="txtSubjectName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />&nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To send your data to database from a web page, you have to either submit it through form or use AJAX. I couldn't find it in your code.